# Accessing a Java Swing GUI from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, updates

I have three classes - class 1 which creates an instance of class 2 (the GUI), class 2 which implements the GUI and class 3 which tries to update the GUI.

In class 1 I create the GUI like this:

```
s = new ServerSocket(6067);         

//while(true){                              

    Socket ClientSocket = s.accept();   // Accept connections   

    // Create instance of the GUI (class 2) on a new thread     
    work w = cpd.new work();

    Thread t = new Thread(w);
    t.start();


    // Create instance of class 3 that uses the GUI on a new thread             
    Charger cpt = new ChargingPoint(ClientSocket, w.gui);   
    cpt.start();                                                
//}


class work implements Runnable{

    GUI gui;

    public void run(){

        try{

            gui = new GUI();
            gui.setVisible(true);                   
        }

        catch(Exception e){}

    }
}
```

In class 2 I implement the GUI and have some methods that allow it to be updated such as this one:

```
public void updateConsole(String text){
    Console.append(text + "\n");
}
```

In class 3 I try to use these methods like below but the code gets stuck when it reaches a statement like this:

```
gui.updateConsole("Data: " + data);
```

This has worked for me before when I had the GUI class (class 2) as the main class.  I passed an instance of this to all the other classes and they could us this to update the GUI without any issues.  This time however I am creating the GUI from another class (class 1) and this method is no longer working and I'm struggling to work out why.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note. You appear to be following the callback pattern.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Comment: java convention is that classes should always start with a capital letter.

Comment: Whats the error?  It sounds like your no longer passing the references you need to the classes that need them

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you the tools to debug this yourself.

Try using eclipse or similar debugger.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Start by checking that class2 is actually calling back to the correct instance of the gui class.

With the debugger, you can find an 'object id'. This will tell you the unique id of the object in memory. It is usually the memory pointer.  Check that the id in ChargingPoint matches the id created in Work class. Running methods on the wrong class is the most common mistake with callback.

Then move onto putting a break point in your gui.updateConsole and step into the code.

This should quickly reveal the issue.

Regards